# Regex everything except IP Address

Tags: regex, ip

I have a big txt file and there is a lot of string,space and IP i just want the IP addresses how can i regex everything except IP? i trying some regex to do that but nothing work for eg:

```
(?!([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*
```

but it regex everything except 3 first digit number of ip addresses.
Thank you

Comment: "Regex" is not a verb, what do you want to do? Are you looking for *a regex that __matches__ all IP addresses*? What language/regex dialect are you using?

Comment: I want a regex that match erverything except ip addresses

Comment: But you say you want "only the IP addresses". So I guess you want to *extract* them. Doesn't it make more sense to *match them* instead of *matching everything else*? Because that's a lot easier.

Comment: do you want to get `IP Address` or not?

Comment: I can use PHP or Perl to match every ip addresses and then save them, but i use powergrep and i want match everything except ip addresses

Comment: Could show some sample inputs and desired output?

Answer (score 2):

With your regex you are trying to catch everything is not preceded by a full ip, but any char of an ip is not preceded by a full ip, that's why it is not working. If you have an ip per line, you can use

```
/(.+?)(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(.+)/
```

to catch everything is "sandwiching" an ip (it uses capturing groups). Else with

```
/(.+?)(?=(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/g
```

you match everything is before an ip. Hope it helps.

N.B. I am using (.+?) to avoid catching chars belonging to the ip. It is called "lazy quantifier".